# Loop over a sorted dictionary a specific number of times in a django template

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have a sorted dictionary that contains sort options:

```
sort_options = SortedDict([
    ("importance" , ("Importance" , "warning-sign")),
    ("effort" , ("Effort" , "wrench" , "effort")),
    ("time_estimate" , ("Time Estimate" , "time")),
    ("date_last_completed" , ("Date Last Completed" , "calendar")),
])
```

I'm displaying these options in my template:

```
{% for key, icon in sort_options.items %}<!-- Sort Options -->
    <a class="btn btn-info" href={{ request.path }}?key={{ key }}&orientation=desc><i class="icon-{{ icon.1 }} icon-large"></i></a>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to define the 4 sort options, but I only want to display the first 3 (the remaining options are used elsewhere). I also anticipate adding other sort options that I won't need to be displayed. I could write an if statement with a forloop counter to prevent the last option from displaying, but this seems wasteful.

I found [this filter](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/) but I'm not sure how to combine it with the forloop that needs both the key and the icon data.

How can I write a django template for loop that runs on a dictionary and only loops X number of times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Joe's answer, but there's actually [a built-in filter `slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) that'll do this for you:

```
{% for key, icon in sort_options.items|slice:":3" %}
```

Comment: Nice, seems simpler than creating a custom tag. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with a template filter.  For example, in:

**./mymodules/templatetags/mytags.py**

```
@register.filter
def get_recent(object, token):
    """
    Must pass a Option Dictionary 
    """
    return object.items()[:token]
```

And then in your template:

```
{% load mytags %}

{% for option in sort_options|get_recent:3 %}
    key: {{ option.0  }} 
    value: {{ option.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't had a chance to test the above code, but think the logic is sound.  Let me know what you think.